# SOAP UI - I can't configure JDBC on SOAP UI, can't find a way to fix this

Tags: mysql, jdbc, soapui

I switched back from SOAP UI Pro to SOAP UI. I don't see a option to add database configurations.

I also tried downloading mysql-connector and adding it in my C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\ext location.

Please click the link to see my error image.

[image]

Comment: JDBC configuration is a -Pro only feature.

Comment: For your error, remove the property "id" and try the connection again.

Comment: I tried, removing id. 
Still doesn't work..

Comment: Remove "MySql/" from the Driver field.

Comment: I figured it out, forgot to mention my database name: Auth

Thank you!